# Python and measuring the time in ms and aborting if threshhold is met

Tags: python, timer, decorator, resolution

I am using nginx, web.py, fastcgi, and redis as my stack.

Upon a post request I have 120 ms to return a response so I need to always measure the response and if about to approach the threshold I need to abort and return False.  I dont get punished if true or false, only if I exceed the 120 threshold where its an exception.   I expect 10-50K qps.

I can simply do if conditions but I am concerned about a long running process and I will have to wait to end before I find out it took to long e.g. a redis call where I am using pipelining. For example

```
start = time.time()
r.get()
end = time.time - start
if end>115 then return False
```

if r.get() takes too e.g. 130ms long then I get punished.

What is python best practice to monitor time and send an abort signal without the monitoring process not taking up too much resources?  Do I fire up a thread?

Do I use a timeout? if So then how in the MS range?

Thanks

Comment: If this is a single-threaded program and if you are on POSIX, you can use signals. If not, you'll need a separate thread for checking the timeout. The problem here is that you can't "abort" the request thread if it takes too long. Would that be a problem?

Comment: Hi,  Well...I just need to return false if takes to long.  But, I can wait for the thread to finish.  Make sense?

Comment: Also..the program is single threaded.

Comment: In that case, just run the request in a separate worker thread and `sleep` in the checker thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use for a [decorator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) in Python. Somebody has already written a [@timeout decorator](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/timeout) that you can use this way:

```
@timeout(timeout=2)
def return_later():
    time.sleep(3)
    return 'later'
```

Since sleep time > timeout, instead of returning 'later' it will generation an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
TimeoutException
```

However because the implementation uses `signal.alarm()` which only takes an `int`, you can't specify a fraction of a second, only whole seconds. Since it looks like you want to use milliseconds you could adapt this decorator to use `signal.setitimer()`. Or an even better solution if you're intrepid enough is to [submit a patch the way someone did to implement setitimer functionality](http://bugs.python.org/issue2240) to the `signal` module to support `ualarm()` which provides microsecond resolution and is simpler to use than `setitimer()`.

Comment: This sounds great use the decorator and try catch the error return a default value if the error is caught.

Comment: Totally awesome.  I replaced signal.alarm(self.timeout) with signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL,self.timeout).  Worked great!